# Unable to mock the environment variable while testing Fast API code using pytest

Tags: python-3.x, rest, pytest, fastapi, pytest-mock

I have a simple fast api code as follow `main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os

app = FastAPI(root_path=f"/{os.environ['EnvName']}/")

@app.get("/getrecord")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Below is the pytest code `test_getrecord.py`

```
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

def test_dummy_api():
    monkeypatch.setenv("EnvName", "dummy")
    client=TestClient(app)
    response = client.get("/getrecord")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

when running the above pytest code `pytest -v ./test/test_getrecord.py` getting below error:

```
(FaSTAPIApplication) C:\Users\abc\Documents\FastAPIWork\FastAPIHttpWrapper>pytest -v ./test/test_getrecord.py
============================================================ test session starts ============================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.11, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- c:\users\abc\anaconda3\envs\fastapiapplication\python.exe   
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\abc\Documents\FastAPIWork\FastAPIHttpWrapper
collected 0 items / 1 error

================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================
__________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/test_getrecord.py __________________________________________________ 
test\test_getrecord.py:5: in <module>
    from main import app
main.py:4: in <module>
    app = FastAPI(root_path=f"/{os.environ['EnvName']}/")
..\..\..\anaconda3\envs\fastapiapplication\lib\os.py:681: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'EnvName'
========================================================== short test summary info ========================================================== 
ERROR test/test_getrecord.py - KeyError: 'EnvName'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

please provide a resolution for this issue, thanks in advance!

Comment: The environment is evaluated when you're doing `from main import app` - patching it later in your code won't do anything useful. It'd probably be better to move the app creation to a fixture that either recreates or reconfigures the app in this case, or set up the environment for all the tests before the code runs (session fixture: `@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)`) for example.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for your suggestion, I have tried moving the set up of environment variable into the pytest fixture but still no luck, do you have any reference to any blog or code snippet which I can refer, I am very net to pytest, thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Came here to find the same answer and figured it out from @MatsLindh comment.

> It'd probably be better to move the app creation to a fixture that either recreates or reconfigures the app in this case, or set up the environment for all the tests before the code runs (session fixture: @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True))

I took this as, "Hey, you should import the app after you set the desired env var."

I tried this

```
@pytest.fixture(name="client", scope="session", autouse=True)
def create_client():
    os.environ["INSERT_ENV_VAR_KEY"] = "INSERT_ENV_VAR_VALUE"
    from main import app

    client = TestClient(app)
    yield client
```

and it worked! Hope this helps.